Getting variable $file got invalid value {}; Upload value invalid
I am trying to upload an image to strapi but I can't find a way to fix this error, what am I doing wrong? I checked the formData and it's not empty.
My mutation:
export const UPLOAD_IMAGE = gql`
   mutation upload($file: Upload!) {
      upload(file: $file) {
         data {
            id
            attributes {
               url
            }
         }
      }
   }
`;

How I am trying to upload the file:
   const [formData, setFormData] = useState<FormData>(new FormData());

   const handleFileChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      if (!e.target.files) return;
      const selectedFile = e.target.files[0];

      const dataUrl = URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile);

      formData.append('files', selectedFile);

      setImageUrl(dataUrl);
      console.log(imageUrl);
   };

 const updateDataHandler = useCallback(
      async (data: FieldValues) => {
         const response = await uploadImage({
            variables: {
               file: formData,
            },
         });

         const uploadedFileId = response.data.map((f: { id: number }) => f.id);

         await updateProfile({
            variables: {
               id: userState?.info?.id,
               data: {
                  profileImage: uploadedFileId,
               },
            },
         });
         setFormData(new FormData());
      },
      [updateProfile, userState?.info?.id, formData, uploadImage],
   );

